# How do I solve the Valuerror problem that appears when using the optimize.curve_fit function in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, data-modeling

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried to see if the shape of ydata and t are the same and they are in fact the same. The only thing that works is when I slice the output of the integrate.odeint function using [:,1] to give me the curve fit of didt. But the thing is, I require all three curves because I plan on graphing all three results. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from scipy import optimize 
from scipy import integrate
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


N0=10203134 #susceptible population
ydata=np.array(df_plot.Jordan[253:]) #beginning on 1/10/2020
t=np.arange(len(ydata))
I0=ydata[0]  #initial conditions
R0=4821
S0=N0-I0-R0



def SIR_Model(SIR,t,beta,alpha):
    S,I,R=SIR
    dsdt=-beta*S*I/N0
    didt=beta*S*I/N0 -alpha*I
    drdt=alpha*I
    return dsdt,didt,drdt


def fit_ode(x,beta,alpha):
    return integrate.odeint(SIR_Model,(S0,I0,R0),t,args=(beta,alpha))

print(ydata.shape)
print(t.shape)

popt,pcov=optimize.curve_fit(fit_ode,t,ydata)
perr=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
print("standard deviation errors:",str(perr))
print("Optimal Parameters: Beta=",popt[0], "alpha:",popt[1])

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-aa1bb286dbba> in <module>
----> 1 popt,pcov=optimize.curve_fit(fit_ode,t,ydata)
      2 perr=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
      3 print("standard deviation errors:",str(perr))
      4 print("Optimal Parameters: Beta=",popt[0], "alpha:",popt[1])
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    782         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    783         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 784         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    785         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    786         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    408     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    409         args = (args,)
--> 410     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    411     m = shape[0]
    412 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    482     if transform is None:
    483         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 484             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    485     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    486         def func_wrapped(params):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (138,3) (138,)
```

Comment: Should it be `def fit_ode(t,beta,alpha):`?

Comment: @mikuszefski I tried that as well. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Could you please add import statements so that we know what are variables `integrate` and others meant to represent?

Comment: @sanitizedUser I just added the import statements. Not all are used in this part of the code. integrate is part of the scipy library.

Comment: But if the slicing is you only problem, you slice for the fit and recalculate the output with the best fit parameters for printing without slicing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your approach works. But I want to see whether I can find all outputs without slicing. This is where I ended up with valuerror.

Comment: Well, if function f1 takes arguments of type A and function f2 has output of type B, you have to write a wrapper, one way or the other. E.g. I'd use `least_squares` where you have to write the residual function yourself, i.e. you can / have to implement the wrapper directly.